# Ajax request is deleting my elements on success

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax request in a javascript tag. When the back end sends response data and the success function is called,it deletes my element("even when that success data is nothing") but when the backend never sends the response back it doesnt delete my element. Why? And how do i stop it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",url: "upload", data: datas, cache: false,contentType: 
    false,processData: false, enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    success: (data)=>
    {

     //this is literally it... even when this is empty it deletes my element
    }
});
```

Comment: Which element was removed?

Comment: we need to see full flow of code

Comment: My guess is you probably forgot to use `event.preventDefault()` in the event listener, so the page is reloading.